# Getting Access denied error in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have following javascript code written in an html page. This html page is kept on desktop and is used to trigger webservice; i am running this from IE9 browser but since this week i have started getting "Access Denied" error at "httpRequest.open" call. I have tried changing security settings for IE but it doesn't work. Same code use to work a week before and still it works just for one person and we are not able to make out the difference as all browser settings are same.

```
function invokeService(name,url) 
{   
    try 
    {
        alert("entering"); 

        if (window.ActiveXObject) 
        {
            alert("activex");
            httpRequest=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
        }
        else if(window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            alert("xmlhttp");
            httpRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 

        alert("going to open"+url); 

        httpRequest.open('GET',url,true);

        alert("opened");

        if (httpRequest.overrideMimeType) 
        { 
            httpRequest.overrideMimeType("text/xml"); 
        }

        alert("Going to pd");

        httpRequest.onreadystatechange=populateDiv;

        alert("going to send");

        httpRequest.send();

        valTimeout=setTimeout("timeout(httpRequest);",1200000);        

    }
    catch(e) 
    { 
        alert("Error in invoke"+e.description); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: @sircapsalot: Only reason i say that is because its working for one and not for others.

Comment: Whats the url? Most likely you have a cross-domain problem. Note that even running a server as `localhost` isn't the same domain when you are access your html file directly from the filesystem.

Comment: @Matt: I agree its cross domain problem. Url is of our server [company.com domain] while the file is kept on desktop. Is there any way out for this? I can't move html page to server.

Comment: You will need to move it to your server and have it be accessed under the same domain.